# How to print datas from API in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**ANGULARJS**

```
 $scope.storePrint= function(salesfilter){
        var url = CONFIG.apiUrl + '/store';
        window.open(url);
        window.print(url);
    };
```

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="storePrint(salesfilter)" type="button">Print</button>
```

I need to  window.print() JSON data from API. How to do this.

Comment: [window.print()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp) doesn't receive any parameters, so you can't call it as you're trying to.
Why don't you try doing a $http request and displaying the whole result as a parsed JSON?

Answer (score 0):

there is no option to pass a url to window.print(), as far as i know.

you could open a new blank page with your data and trigger the print call there:

```
<html>
  <head> ... </head>
  <body>
    <pre>{some: "data"}</pre>
    <script>window.print()</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

or you write the data to a hidden element on your current page and show that element only when printing.